# Plans to make Android Apps run on Ubuntu abandoned?

Tags: android, history-of-ubuntu

I remember a longer time ago there was an anouncement that some Ubuntu developers were planing to bring the possibility to Ubuntu to run Android Apps on an Ubuntu and planned to write an environment for this purpose.

Since this announcement i havn't heard again anything about this plans. And via Google nothing couldn't be found.

Are these plans abandoned?

Comment: Interestingly, with the advent of HTML 5 and the pending demise of Flash, it may render apps obsolete in just a few years anyway; HTML 5 will be supported on all major platforms including Apple, Windows and Android.

Developers would rather develop an application once (on HTML 5) rather than multiple times (once for desktop, once for iPad and iPhone, and once for Android).

Comment: It is now possible to run some of Android apps in Google Chrome Linux version with hacks (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/09/install-android-apps-ubuntu-archon) so I don't think Canonical will revive or continue their own plan; Google and developers are now doing what Canonical once planned.

Answer (score 7):

The original plans were presented by [Debbie Beliveau](https://launchpad.net/~debbie-beliveau) and [Michael Frey](https://launchpad.net/~mfrey). If you want to know what happened to *their* plans, you'd probably do best to ping them an email. *Most* Ubuntu developers don't bite and I'm sure they'd be happy to explain.

Actually, I'm curious about this too, so I'll send them both an email now. I'll post back with any response.

There have been rumblings of activity elsewhere since in other distributions but I've never seen anything as positive as the UDS presentation a couple of years ago.

There is a way to run *some* Android applications inside Ubuntu: [you install the Android software development kit](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Run-Android-Applications-on-Ubuntu-115152.shtml) and run applications on a virtual device. Far from perfect but perhaps enough for simple needs.

Comment: I think looking at the speed of development of Unity in comparison with the complete lack of progress on android-ubuntu cross compatability https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/mobile-karmic-android-execution-environment finished in june 2009 and..... but looking at what the original people involved are doing now (ARM) I would say that including unity ubuntu might be looking to shape up as an alternative to Android..... just incase. Now that is completely wild speculation but sounds kind of interesting

Comment: thanks fluteflute, very interested in what they will answer. i know the android dev kit and already used it, but for general purposes the emulator isn't comparably to an runtime environment.

Comment: @Allan: i think a great advantages of Android is the number of great and versatile apps. using them in ubuntu would be great.

Comment: Answer was from me, not fluteflute ;) He just removed the first line.

Comment: ah sorry. thanks oli, looking forward any news you can provide.

Comment: Actually, the Android SDK will run almost all Android applications.

Comment: @George how well does it handle OpenGL and other multimedia?

Comment: @Oli: It just uses a test pattern for the camera. I haven't tried any OpenGL stuff. Multimedia works, but is notably slow.

Comment: some interesting news: Android apps to run on non-android devices with ‘Alien Dalvik’http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/android-apps-coming-to-non-android-phones-maybe-even-ubuntu

Comment: Sorry for the rant here, but I can't believe that Canonical put all this effort into Unity, etc. to make Ubuntu work on a Tablet when Android is already there. IMO that effort should have been spent creating a synthesized Ubuntu/Android environment where we get the best of both worlds, but on a traditional large screen, multi-processor CPU, keyboard & mouse driven computer.  Ubuntu will eventually win the desktop war, just in time for nobody to care.

Answer (score 0):

May be http://www.android-x86.org/ running in kvm could be an answer. Better than running development kit anyway.